# jquery How do I add a class to span within a dl based on the text it contains?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to add the class="st_sharethis" to the menu link: Tell A Friend on this site http://www.easyspacedesign.com/fh/ConnectBell_/. There is no way to add a specific class or id to a menu link in the cms we use so going to have to use jquery to do it.

So I will have to do it based on the text within the span tag that is within the a tag.

So far i have tried:

```
  $('.main_menu span:contains("Tell A Friend")').attr('class','st_sharethis');

  $('.main_menu span').each(function ()
  {
    if ($(this).text() == "Tell A Friend")
    $(this).attr('id','rev3');
  }
```

neither has worked.

Comment: Are you hitting your target at all. If it's a span within an a tag, where is the a tag in your jQuery selector. Try something simple, like changing the text color to find out if your hitting your target, or in the last example try alerting the returned text to see that it is in fact the text your are checking for equality. Another option would be to post the HTML here, that way it would be possible to help you more spesifically, and not just with some general considerations. Last example is missing characters in the if statement, won't work at all, and not sure you can use contains like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for your markup:

```
$('#menu span:contains("Tell A Friend")')
           .addClass('st_sharethis')
           .attr('id','rev3');
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ydFFR/

Answer (score 0):

If this menu item will always be latest one:

```
$('#menu dl dt:last a').addClass('myclass');
```

Also, you have specific class `last` on this menu item, so you can:

```
$('dt.last').addClass('myClass');
```

Or you can just test content of the link:

```
$('#menu dl dt a span:contains("Tell A Friend")').parent().addClass('myClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

The following adds a class and id to the element.

```
$('.main_menu span:contains("Tell A Friend")')
    .addClass('st_sharethis')
    .attr('id', 'rev3');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, you just need to add a ");" at the end!

```
 $('.main_menu span:contains("Tell A Friend")').attr('class','st_sharethis');

   $('.main_menu span').each(function ()
   {
     if ($(this).text() == "Tell A Friend")
     $(this).attr('id','rev3');
   }
 );   // ADD this line !
```

But of course it would be better to just chain the commands:

```
 $('.main_menu span:contains("Tell A Friend")')
  .attr('class','st_sharethis')
  .attr('id','rev3');
```

Comment: Yes I tested this, it's interpreted as an inline 'if' (\n characters don't matter in javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If its the last, try

```
$('a.main_menu.last').find('span').addClass('st_sharethis');
```